# using http link in informatica power center

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have the http link http://gws2.maps.yahoo.com/findlocation?flags=J&location

For this linik I have to give the input as Address fields(country, city,zipcode) and the output fields are:latitude, longitude, sub-region, and region

How can i achieve through this from informatica?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved through HTTP transformation by connecting the output of the HTTP Transformation to XML parser transformation

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it using a HTTP transformation.

Comment: do you know where to add proxy setting for Http Transformation?

Comment: You have to setup proxy at integration service level using the admin console.